# Understanding webhooks

Tags: php

I'm kinda new to this part of programming, and I find it really confusing.

I have a script that makes some contact with a third party api.
It basically adds a customer to their data.

What I heard is that they do something on the background, that checks if the newly added customer paid.

When their system notifies that, they're basically making an api call to a custom route of mine, and send a json object to that route.

I googled a bit, and came to this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('sportivity-callback', '/endpoint', [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'rest_api_init',
    ]);
});

function rest_api_init($request){
    $json = $request->get_json_params();
    return $json;
}
```

Am I explaining it right? Here I use the rest api init hook. I register a custom route, for the third party. I add a method to that route. that returns the json, that they've sent.

Comment: Yes, this is a fairly common pattern e.g. payment providers, some of the oAuth2 flows. I'm a bit lost though: what are you asking / what do you need help with? What to do with the JSON they send you? I'd guess just update the customer / order / whatever you sent to them in your database.

Comment: I'd be surprised if their callback was a GET though. I'd expect it to be a POST and them to post the JSON content.

Comment: @Rup I basically need to inserrt a membership whenever they retrieve a customer ID. But I'm not sure how to test this. I went to the route and it just gave me a 404. Also I changed it to a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I managed to fix it

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('endpoint', '/sportivity', [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'sportivity_endpoint',
    ]);
});

function sportivity_endpoint($request){
    $json = $request->get_json_params();
    $json['test'] = 'Jan';
    return $json;
}
```

When I go to url/wp-json/endpoint/sportivity it returns the json now.

Answer (score 0):

OKay used this code to work on my first webhook and sat for hours and could not get my custom code to work the way I wanted.
And could NOT get POST to work in postman... and OMG
Till I spotted one thing on another site

```
'method' => 'POST',
```

IS WRONG, It's Plural... Grrrr Plz be aware of this
it's

```
'methods' => 'POST',
```